# How to Append Sum variable in csv using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, ado.net, append

I want show Sum in csv format and I am able to calculate sum but not able to append SUM variable on Particular column.
How can append my variable on Particular column  `(Where i need to add sum variable ?)`

Code:

```
int sum = 0;
daB.SelectCommand = CmdB;
daB.Fill(dtB);
foreach (DataRow dr in dtB.Rows)
 {
  sum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["ORDER_QTY"]);
 }
string csv = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRow dr in dtB.Rows)
 {
     foreach (DataColumn column in dtB.Columns)
       {
        csv += dr[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
       }
  csv += "\r\n";
                            
  }
```

Sample Data:

[image]

Comment: Add the sum to end of line (the CSV) by adding".  With your code: csv +=  a comma, the sum (as a string)and then the return.  So line would look like following :   csv + "," + sum.ToString() + "\r\n"  or csv += "," + sum.ToString() + "\r\n";

Comment: @jdweng yes you are correct but sum is showing at first column, But i want to show 3rd last column how can i pass column index in csv?

Comment: Thnx i increase "," its working like champ thnx alot